How to make a constrained asset camera real?
I have an asset which is a collection of 2 objects: a path and a camera tracked to it with a constraint. 
When I place that asset in a blender file and select Object -> Apply -> Make Instances Real both objects from the collection become "local/real" but the camera's constraints disappear.
Is there a way to retain the constraints when making the asset's instance real? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?
